# How I can show ScrollView scroll-bar for 2 seconds on activity create?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I just want to show the scrollbar for 2 sec when view is created. Is there any attribute for this?

> Actually it show when user touch the screen but I want to show it automatically for a few seconds so user can know this view is scroll-able.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="2000"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the android:id attribute in the xml for ScrollView and in the activity use timer or countdowntimer for 2 sec notification and on completion set the visibility of the ScrollView
 to invisible.

Comment: He, I am not asking for hiding the ScrollView. But only the scroll-bar of the ScrollView. Actually it show when user touch the screen but I want to show it automatically for a few seconds so user can know this view is scroll-able.

Comment: after showing scrollbar for 2 secs set this property to your view:  yourview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

Comment: Mean I have to do this using code. Ok. If I did not find any other good solution I will implement this code. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- Make a call to move the scrollView (e.g. mScrollView.scrollBy(0, 1)) if you don't mind the view scrolling by a pixel.  This will call through to onScrollChanged and subsequently awaken the scroll bars.  If you call something like scrollBy(0, 0), the scrollView realizes it doesn't need to do anything and won't shown the scroll bars.
- Create a subclass of ScrollView the publicly exposes the awakenScrollBars() method, which is protected by default.  [See here for details.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/view/View.java#View.awakenScrollBars%28%29)

Comment: Thanks! I did the trick this way:
`mScrollView.scrollBy(0, -1);
mScrollView.scrollBy(0, 1);` That is the shortest solution I think

Answer (score 0):

check out this link(android:scrollbarFadeDuration)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarFadeDuration

or try this..

```
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
```

Comment: I this. But not show bars until touch the screen. I want to show automatically on create.